# Surefire system property not being set

Tags: maven, junit, mule, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to get our Mule tests to run with verbose exceptions, but I cannot get the surefire plugin to set the appropriate system property correctly, here is my surefire config:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <mule.verbose.exceptions>true</mule.verbose.exceptions>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
```

Now if I run maven with the command -Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true it prints verbose exceptions, but will not if I do a simple mvn test.  Why are my system properties being ignored here?

Comment: Have you tried the old way? 
    <systemProperties>
            <property>
              <name>propertyName</name>
              <value>propertyValue</value>
            </property>
            [...]
          </systemProperties>

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked the code but it could be caused by a static check that is performed previous to the surefire initialization. I would rather try the special variables mechanism described in the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html#Special_VM_Properties).